# iOS 8 and Xcode 6 Simulator Display Out of Alignment

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

The display is stuck on zoomed in. I did a clean install Xcode install and it's still broken.

[image]

Comment: Window -> Scale -> 50%?

Comment: Nope still doesn't do anything. I've tried everything not sure what else I could do.

Comment: What type of configuration do you have for your displays?  Do you have a mix of retina and normal displays?  I've seen a report of this happening when dragging the window between a retina display to a normal one.

Comment: You could've accidentally activated the accessibility "zoom" feature.

Comment: Try "Reset Contents and Settings" in the simulator if the accessibility zoom isn't the issue.

Comment: Reset Contents & Settings is irrelevent here.  Zoom is irrelevant here.  Please answer my questions above.  Also indicate your OS version as a duplicate recent question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068162/ios-8-and-xcode-6-simulator-display-out-of-alignment) suggests this may have been introduced by the 10.10.2 beta seed.

Comment: Still no luck, the simulator is broken

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Simulator display scaled incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432274/ios-simulator-display-scaled-incorrectly)

Comment: The temporary fix: http://youtu.be/4gkFEkOJN9s

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/42166559/2913356 for another (temporal) fix

Answer (score 0):

I just updated to the Xcode 6.2 Beta and it works on the retina display of my macbook. Unfortunately it just shows a white screen on my main monitor ...

Maybe the want to force me to use the MB screen as a simulator display ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Having the same issue since the Yosemite beta update.

It's definitely not a permanent fix but moving the simulator to a screen with a different pixel scale factor makes the simulator usable on one or another of the screens.