# iOS simulator scaled bug

Tags: ios, ios-simulator, xcode6, screen, retina-display

Today morning I build and run my xcode project. When simulator launched I saw this:

[image]

The screen is **scaled**, I see only **1/4 part, other 3/4 parts** are **hidden**.
Did anybody faced with same problem? The issue happens in **xCode6, Xcode5**, also in **AppCode**.
I tried to Clean project, switched to **iPhone5 screen**, **iPad**, the same problem.

Also, this happens with my other iOS projects.

Comment: I think this is the Yosemite problem, I've updated it two days ago. But the problem appeared just today. This version of Yosemite (10.10.2 (14C68k)) is buggy, because Chrome browser is crashing, maybe other apps crash too... anyway...

Comment: I've seen some reports of this before, and the issue was caused by dragging the window between retina and non-retina displays.  Was that the case here, or do you only have a retina display?

Comment: Also see duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068162/ios-8-and-xcode-6-simulator-display-out-of-alignment#comment42679648_27068162 (can't yet close due to lack of answer)

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Macbook Pro retina. No external displays.

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia Any suggestions? All I can do while developing iOS projects, it is compiling my project directly to my device. Cann't use simulator anymore. Hope, Apple will pre-release bugfix ASAP.

Comment: Can you please file a radar at http://bugreport.apple.com and we can followup that way?

Comment: You also report that the issue happens on Xcode 5 and that you are on the 10.10.2 beta.  Xcode 5 is not supported on 10.10.2, so please confirm or clarify that.  I am assuming you installed Xcode 5.1.1 from ADC downloads even though it's not supported, is that correct?  If so, that is certainly a strong indication that there may be something about the 10.10.2 SU that is related to this because your report and the other one that I linked to from the day before are the only reports of the issue, both happened the week of the seed, and Xcode 5 certainly hasn't changed in over a year ;).

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia I've Xcode5, Xcode 6.1 and Xcode 6.2 beta. Tested the issue by all of them. They work fine.

Comment: I found a strange regularity, iOS simulator works fine at home, at friend's home, but not at my work (office). Very strange. Now I'm at home, no problem, i can work with iOS simulators )

Comment: Please file a radar as mentioned above, and please include system profiles for your working and dysfunctional system so we can try to narrow down the source of the problem, thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Simulator display scaled incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432274/ios-simulator-display-scaled-incorrectly)

Comment: @JeremyHuddlestonSequoia please watch this video: http://youtu.be/4gkFEkOJN9s

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36108837/1233379) (same issue, different behaviour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Finally,** I **got the reason** why this bug appears at **work** and not at **home** :)

Because at work **I don't have** external display (**monitor**), but at home (DELL, non-retina off course)

If you want this bug not to appear, just connect your macbook to external non-retina monitor. Then you may work fine, run simulator in macbook retina display, also in external monitor display, while Apple hard works to fix this bug in OS X.

Here is the video proof: http://youtu.be/4gkFEkOJN9s

Answer (score -1):

Within the iPhone/iPad simulator, go to the top-menu and select "iOS Simulator" -> "Reset Content and Settings..."

Comment: Try go to the top-menu and select "Window" -> "Scale" -> "50%" ,then restart Xcode and simulator.

Comment: Are you "retina display"?