# iOS simulator showing black on 3/4 of screen

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I tried several apps running in fresh install (yosemite) of Xcode 6.3 simulator but all of them displays only on first 1/4 of simulator screen.

I changed scaling - did not help.
All devices have this problem.
On another mac the apps are displaying in simulator correctly.

Here the screenshot from simulator:

[image]

Comment: please upload the image on imgur or something similar, i will NOT download anything just to help you, it is just a bit too unsafe imho.

Comment: Did you try what is suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097967/ios-simulator-scaled-bug ?

Comment: Yes I did but did not help.

Answer (score 2):

I frequently have this issue with a VMWare OSX development machine I'm using to develop iOS native apps. From what I've seen it is related to the **Window > Scale** menu option being set to something different than 100% from a previous launch that messes around all the subsequent initialization phases.

To get rid of it, try doing this:

- Exit from VMWare *full-screen* mode, switching to *windowed mode* instead.
- launch **iOS Simulator** using its *stand-alone* shortcut (not from XCode) and wait until it finishes loading/booting the default device.
- go to **Window > Scale** and set it to 100%.
- go to **iOS Simulator > Reset contents and settings...** and click OK.
- close and reopen the **iOS Simulator** using its *stand-alone* app (not from XCode).

As soon as you see it loading without the glitch, you can switch back to VMWare *full-screen* mode and also use the **Window > Scale** as you like.