# Xcode's iOS Simulator Leaves Black Space

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

Basically, when I run the iOS Simulator on Xcode, the iDevice isn't scaled to the window correctly. It's not an issue with resizing the window, but rather an issue with the actual device.

Here's a picture for reference.

[image]

Is there a way that I can fix this? Restarting the simulator doesn't resolve the issue, unfortunately. I've also tried restarting Xcode, which doesn't work either.

Comment: Try reseting content and settings. iOS Simulator > Reset Content And Settings.

Comment: What Xcode version are you running?

Comment: Resetting content and settings didn't work. I'm also running Xcode 6.3.2.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097967/ios-simulator-scaled-bug maybe?

Answer (score 1):

For this issue you have to just restart the simulator.

Comment: Rather then answer you need to post as a comment.

Comment: i don't have sufficient reputation to add comments.

Comment: Restarting the simulator doesn't resolve the issue, unfortunately. I've also tried restarting Xcode, which doesn't work either

Comment: @NeonSamuel what's wrong with this, if it indeed rectifies the OPs issues? If it's an answer it's an answer, and this answer could be the one that helps the OP move forward with his project, just because it's <= 10 words doesn't make it not an answer. However, BKjadav, the OP already stated restarting the simulator didn't conclude with a different outcome. So just make sure your reading the questions carefully

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is a sizing issue with the simulator. Try hitting Command 1, Command 2, then Command 3 quickly one after the next. Do this a few times and it should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, these scaling issues in the Simulator were due to a bug with Yosemite 10.10.2, and it was addressed in later patches. So think about doing your system updates if you're on this version.

If that fails or you cannot do it for some reason, updating your XCode to 6.4 -you probably want to have the latest SDK installed anyway- may somehow help.