# iOS Simulator display scaled incorrectly

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

I came back to X-code after a few months break. In that time in which x-code wasn't used it was kept updated however.

Now when I Launch the iOS simulator the display is scaled wrong. I have worked at home with an external monitor 1920x1080 and the simulator runs correctly. However when I run the simulator on my Retina display it looks like the image below.

Ive tried resetting the simulator and settings, uninstalling and reinstalling x-code. and several other things but the display is still scaled for a 1920x1080 screen and I don't know how to change that so that its for a Retina display again.

Any Ideas?

Screenshot of simulator display

[image]

Screenshot of what its supposed to look like:

[image]

Comment: Check your auto layout constraints. Which version of Xcode are your using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug in OS X 10.10.2 beta.

> https://devforums.apple.com/thread/243676
>
> https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254997
>
> [iOS simulator scaled bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097967/ios-simulator-scaled-bug)
>
> [iOS 8 and Xcode 6 Simulator Display Out of Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068162/ios-8-and-xcode-6-simulator-display-out-of-alignment)

Also now mentioned in the [Xcode 6.2 beta 3 Release Notes](http://adcdownload.apple.com//Developer_Tools/xcode_6.2_beta_3_y9ikvy/xcode_6.2_beta_3__release_notes.pdf):

> Apps running in the iOS Simulator may not display correctly on a Mac
>   with Retina display running OS X Yosemite 10.10.2 beta. (19079907)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to fix this issue (temporally) is by having the simulator being opened in [Low Resolution](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202471).

How to open the simulator in low resolution:

- Open the simulator from within Xcode
- Right click the simulator in the dock and choose *Options > Show in Finder*
- Right click the simulator in Finder and choose *Get Info*
- Check *Open in Low Resolution*
- Close the simulator
- Reopen the simulator from within Xcode

Answer (score 0):

I have the temporary fix for this OS X bug.

I have this bug at work but not at home, so I thought it's a toggle problem, depending maybe on different internet connections (so stupid decision, anyway) :)

In Apple forum someone mentioned **"external monitor"**, and at that moment I said myself **EUREKA**, we have a fix, but temporary for this bug:

Watch my **video** **proof**: http://youtu.be/4gkFEkOJN9s

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes things that change your display profile fail to change it back, i.e. flux or screenresx.  Your resolution may appear to be the same but it isnt.  I only noticed bc the font rendering seemed ever so slightly fuzzier.  Go to System Settings > Displays and re-select your desired resolution.  This is probably not the answer in most cases, but it helped me this time.