# iOS Simulator only showing bottom left quarter of the screen

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, ios-simulator

Since a few days ago, my iOS Simulator has only been showing the bottom left part of the screen, as you can see in this screen shot:

[iOS Simulator](https://www.dropbox.com/s/du4sroyt15jju5h/Screenshot%202014-12-22%2012.53.17.png?dl=1)

It makes no difference if I am in an App or not, it's always only the bottom left which is shown. I don't know what caused it or since when exactly I had this issue. I am on the latest OS X 10.10.2 beta seed, and the issue exists on both Xcode 6.1.1 and the latest 6.2 beta, and on the simulators 7.1, 8.1 and 8.2 beta.

Here are things I've already tried:

- "Reset content and settings" from the iOS Simulator menu
- Scale -> 100%, 75% and 50%, all with the same issue
- Delete DerivedData and other Xcode caches
- Delete all Simulator-Devices and recreate them from Xcode
- Use resizable Simulator
- Restart Xcode, the Simulator and my rMBP
- Combinations of all of the above

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Simulator display scaled incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432274/ios-simulator-display-scaled-incorrectly)

Comment: Discussed multiple times on SO and devforums and even mentioned in the Xcode 6.2 release notes.

Comment: check the answer in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30272125/screen-content-is-only-shown-in-a-part-of-screen-in-ios-simulator?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with XCode8, OS8 and OS9.

Goto Window > Scale and check 100%. iPhone will become full screen again, iPhone sice however might be larger than your computer screen.

Comment: He wrote that it hadn't helped him