# iOS Simulator drawing too big (not a window scale issue)

Tags: xcode, macos, ios-simulator

Firstly, thanks for your time and effort.

Just today I started having a random issue in my iOS simulator running an app from Xcode 6. No Xcode update has been installed since I last used the simulator so I don't think it is an issue with an update.

Basically, my simulator is drawing everything HUGE. Like 4x the size it should be. This happens with all simulator devices regardless of iOS version. I'm aware of the window scaling with CMD + 1, 2, 3. That is not the issue. It shows the same no matter the scale. When you click or interact with the screen squares of it flicker. This is what it looks like.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgdHv.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJae8.png]

Note that it is not just the application, but also the home screen.

I should also note that this does not seem to be just the simulator. The screen saver on OSX with the words and definitions also is entirely too large. I haven't noticed it in any other application though.

I have done everything I could think of to debug the issue.
I deleted Xcode and reinstalled it with a restart in between.
I have created a new user account on my machine and ran a boilerplate app on the simulator and it displayed the same way.
I've changed my screen resolution to see if that resolves the issue.
I cleared the mysterious PRAM.
None of these solved the issue or made it better or worse.

Again, thanks for your time. It is appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Simulator display scaled incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432274/ios-simulator-display-scaled-incorrectly)

Comment: The temporary fix: http://youtu.be/4gkFEkOJN9s

Comment: With respect to everyone who has written in using the word 'scale' - that is definitively *not* the solution. The original questioner, Caleb, states that the content of the device is what is too large (see the screenshots). Thinking on this, it's as if every application's main view controller is drawing its view bigger than the dimensions of the device. This being the case, simply changing the scale will/does not fix the problem. I too am having exactly the same problem and I have - as yet - not found a suitable answer to solving it. Assuming that this is XCode 7.0 or later - I repeat the moan

Comment: May have an interesting update on this: I've just left the simulator running for over 45 minutes and the contents did, finally shrink to fit the simulator window - although the iPhone's bezel never did appear. It seems that it just takes a very long time for the simulator contents to stabilise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bug in 10.10.2 beta:

- https://devforums.apple.com/thread/243676
- https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254997
- [iOS simulator scaled bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097967/ios-simulator-scaled-bug)
- [iOS 8 and Xcode 6 Simulator Display Out of Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068162/ios-8-and-xcode-6-simulator-display-out-of-alignment)
- [iOS Simulator display scaled incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432274/ios-simulator-display-scaled-incorrectly/27434793#27434793)

Comment: Ah, this seems to be correct. Thank you. I can accept answer, but not enough rep to upvote.

Everything I searched for came up with Window->Scale. I was like that's not it!

Comment: I also just happened to think this is probably related to an issue I noticed this weekend where Spotify's inner view is really big.

Comment: I'm getting same issue 5 months later with Xcode 7 on OS X 10.11.5  MacBook Air from 2011; probably Xcode expects a higher DPI laptop. Any suggestions to fix it?

Answer (score 8):

For me pressing command + 2 or command + 3 when the ios simulator opens up solve the problem. Pressing the above keys do scaled down the simulator size.

Answer (score 1):

I recently started and I had the same issue. You simply have to change the scale. When the iOS Simulator opens, navigate to Window and change the scale; 50% worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to 14C94b, fixed this bug.
I have been to see same problem for Subline Text3
enjoy)