# iOS Simulator Massively Zoomed

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator

It looks like this (what I actually see):
[image: Screenshot using Preview]

However, a screenshot taken from the simulator looks like this:

[image: Screenshot using iOS Simulator]

Here's another pair:

[image: Screenshot using Preview]
[image: Screenshot using iOS Simulator]

I've tried uninstalling the simulators, but that doesn't fix the issue. I've tried 
<kbd>⌘+1</kbd>, <kbd>⌘+2</kbd>, <kbd>⌘+3</kbd>, but that hasn't fixed anything. I think this is because of a recent system upgrade to OS X 10.10.2 and Xcode 6.1.1. Is the easiest/best/only path a full uninstall of Xcode and downloading an older version? Please give me an alternative.

Comment: Are you running an iPhone 6+ ?? I can only imagine that this is a Density/Retina issue...

Comment: Retina monitor, right?

Comment: @matt Yes, it's an rMBP.

Comment: @jesses.co.tt It's the same for all iOS simulators. I've tried with iPhone 4S, 5, 5S, 6, 6 Plus, iPad 2, iPad Retina, etc...

Comment: Yeah, this is a known bug. Sorry, that's all I know. But I've seen this mentioned on SO before.

Comment: I'm running OS X 10.10.2 (14C81f) and Xcode 6.1.1 (6A2008a) on a 13" Retina MBP, and haven't seen this issue.

Comment: @matt Really? I couldn't find anything except for one question that had instructions that were actually impossible to follow.

Comment: @mbm29414 Can you see if your build#s match mine?

Comment: @AaronBrager Yup. Perfect match. And I've rebooted, restarted Xcode, etc... All the standard stuff.

Comment: the screenshot is alway equal to the resolution of the simulator, iPhone 5 (640* 1136), iPhone 6 (750 x 1334) & iPhone 6 Plus (1242 x 2208)

Comment: @zaheer Yes. The iOS Simulator window is the correct size. Screen shots taken from the simulator come out the correct size and have all the image data you'd expect. The iOS Simulator window itself it just "zoomed". It's going to really suck to only be able to test on my devices and not the simulator.

Comment: @AaronBrager Is yours a retina MBP? That's where the issue is.

Comment: @matt He said it's a 13" rMBP.

Comment: @matt [MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Late 2013)](http://www.everymac.com/ultimate-mac-lookup/?search_keywords=FH04)

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS Simulator display scaled incorrectly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432274/ios-simulator-display-scaled-incorrectly)

Comment: why not resize your simulator to 50%, or 75%?

Comment: @DebanjanChakraborty The "scale" of the simulator (100%, 75%, 50%) doesn't matter. I mentioned that in my post. Per JeremyHuddlestonSequ below, this is a well-known and reported bug.

Comment: The temporary fix: http://youtu.be/4gkFEkOJN9s

Comment: @AlmasAdilbek I saw that and commented. I've got a multi-monitor setup and I'm about to test your solution. I expect it to work and I'm really thankful to you for posting that video!

Answer (score 0):

This is a known bug in OS X 10.10.2 beta.

1. https://devforums.apple.com/thread/243676
2. https://devforums.apple.com/thread/254997
3. [iOS simulator scaled bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27097967)
4. [iOS 8 and Xcode 6 Simulator Display Out of Alignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27068162)
5. [iOS Simulator display scaled incorrectly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27432274)
6. [iOS Simulator drawing too big (not a window scale issue)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27491464)

Comment: Thanks. I searched for "zoomed", but didn't search for "scaled". I actually searched for 10-15 minutes for my problem before posting. Guess I was tired and my google-fu was weak! ;-)